# How do you give in honor/memory of someone but acknowledge someone else?

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit, honoree

In some other donation management software, it's possible to say, e.g., "I'm giving $100 in memory of my grandfather.  I want my mother and uncle to be acknowledged."

Has anyone tried to incorporate such a workflow into CiviCRM?  How do you best do it?  Do you soft credit my grandmother? Or my mother/uncle?  How do you generate reports of who needs acknowledging?

Comment: Maybe it's a cultural thing but I don't understand what you mean by 'acknowledge' in this context...  Could you soft credit to all but with different soft credit types for mother/uncle vs grandfather?

Comment: Ah - I mean I want to send a "letter of acknowledgment" - a thank-you letter of sorts - to the mother and uncle.  It's not uncommon here at funerals for the family to say, "In lieu of flowers, the family asks that you make a donation to X charity". In such a case, you want to ensure the family is made aware of the donations made in the name of the deceased.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the purpose of gathering soft credits and acknowledging the donation. For acknowledgement purposes it may be sufficient to gather email and name (and perhaps address) on a front or backend form and with a hook send off an acknowledgement email. I think this can be very nice for those related to the honoured person, allowing them to send a thank you card if they want. Personally I won't bother creating additional soft credits for the mother and uncle beyond those for the person in honour/memory of.

Answer (score 1):

I recalled that my former coworker wrote an "acknowledgee" extension to handle a similar situation and put it on my Github.  You can find it here: https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.ccr.acknowledgee.

It's rough around the edges, but a) it adds a set of fields to the contribution page if "in memory of" is selected; b) if you have a contribution custom field "Acknowledgee" of type "Contact Reference", it will populate that field with the contact ID that is created/updated.